# facebook functionality

Tags: facebook, fbml

On many pages in facebook I have seen this[image]

It looks like it is embedded html code. What is the name of that functionality in facebook and how to build my own ?

Comment: Please remove php from the tags.

Answer (score 0):

FBML is being phased out by facebook in favor of iframes. What you are seeing as an iframe embedded inside a page tab.
This is a good tutorial to get you started:
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframe-application-to-facebook-fan-page/

Answer (score 0):

It was accomplished adding the [Static FBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878) application to your page.

As per March 18, 2011, adding this app is no longer possible. <sup>([source](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-announces-new-static-fbml-cutoff-march-18-2011/))</sup>

What you can do instead is [make your own iFrame application](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframe-application-to-facebook-fan-page/), and add that as a tab.